# Can PDI output multiple Excel files based on Content?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I have a database table that has two columns - date and name.

The date column is in a standard YYYYMMDD format, and the name column is just a set of unique random names.

Assuming the table contains the following content:

Date|Name

20231201|Ben

20231202|Jerry

20231203|Wendy

20231304|Ronald

20231304|Klaus

I would like to use the Excel output/Writer step to product separate Excel files based on the content of this database table.

My expected outcome would be having 5 files in the output folder with files named as:

1. 20231201-Ben.xls
2. 20231202-Jerry.xls
3. 20231203-Wendy.xls
4. 20231204-Ronald.xls
5. 20231205-Klaus.xls

Each file will contain again two columns of Date and Name, listing it's respective values from the first database table.

How can I achieve this using the Microsoft Excel Output/Writer steps?

Answer (score 1):

I have an old version of Pentaho (8.2) but it seems like the *Excel Writer/Output* steps haven't changed in the new versions.

The *Text file output* step allows you to use an incoming column in your stream of data to use as file name, you could create a csv file with that step, not an Excel file.

But those Excel steps don't allow it, so you would have to use Metadata Injection to achieve this, you create a template transformation to generate your files and another transformation reads the metadata and injects the values like the file name to the template.

Comment: Completely correct. If the number of files is small then you can still just code it in, but 4+ diffrent files, I would use Ana's solutions which is in this situation the best solution. +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple excel file output based on the input data. You can first create a desired filename using the `JavaScript` or `Java Expressions step`.

Then use the `Copy rows to Result` and `Get rows from result` to iterate the data every row to generate the excel files. The steps are documented in the below [blog site](https://tech-spaghetti.com/2014/12/23/using-copy-rows-to-result-in-pentaho-data-integration/#solution-b-using-get-rows-from-result).